# Set article title as page title

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need to set the article title as page title. Please, note that my articles are not menu items because my menu is built on a custom module.
Please, advise.
Thank you.

Comment: and what is your current page title? is it other than your article title?

Comment: my current page title in the articles is the main page title, on all articles

Comment: @manton please progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a plugin for this event:

onContentPrepare

and code something like:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setTitle( $article->title);
```

I can give you a more elaborated code if you needed.

Comment: Yes, I 'd be grateful if you did, because I am not an expert on coding. Where should I place that code? Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: @Piero please respond to the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page title in Backend Global Configuration. The URL is

`/administrator/index.php?option=com_config`

if you want to define the separator check: [Where can I configure the page title separator from "-" to "|"?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24106/where-can-i-configure-the-page-title-separator-from-to)