# Where can I configure the page title separator from "-" to "|"?

Tags: configuration, global-configuration

I cannot find a option in Joomla where to configure the page title separator?
Default seems to be "-" and I would like to have "|"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Languages > Overrides
2. Select your site language[image]
3. Create a new override
4. Enter **JPAGETITLE** in the *Language Constant* text box
5. Enter **%1$s | %2$s** in the *Text* textarea[image]

Comment: @laendle you are welcome :)